# How can I record a call transfer with freeSwitch?

Tags: voip, sip, freeswitch

I am using freeSwitch to terminate calls that originate on the local network from an IVR system.  I have it working with several different voip terminators, and I can record sessions successfully, except when the call gets transferred.  When I do a transfer, I see two WAV files, one of which is the original session in which I can hear the call up until the transfer.  The other file is all silence, which I assume is the session up to the point where the INVITE is answered.  But I get no audio of the conversation after the transfer.  My suspicion is that freeSwitch is not hairpinning the audio, so it does not have access to the RTP.

I pasted everything from the console at http://pastebin.freeswitch.org/16027.

Comment: Have you set "recording follow transfer=true" in your default.xml file ?